# Get street segment (polygon or start point + end point) from street name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, gis, geocoding

I am trying to obtain and "highlight" a whole street given the street name, sort of what google does when you write a street name and hit search.

Street segment :

[image: street segment]

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: There is no Google API to do this.  It can be done, but you need (at least) the start and end points for the street ([example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=(55.677504,12.582333)&geocode=1&addr2=(55.678785,12.585023)&geocode=2) using the directions service).

Comment: Although, depending on what you want to do, the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) might do what you want, but it seems to just mark the center of the road (the geocoder result for that road)..

Comment: @geocodezip yeah I have a partially working solution which among other things uses the directions service. I wonder if there's any way to get the last known number of a given street. cause likely a street starts at #1 but the end number is unknown (?)

Comment: I actually did solve this. And no, you dont need start and end points of the street. i solved it using the overpass-api.

Comment: You should probably provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this doing the following:

1. Using the overpass-api (http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter) with something like this: `[out:json];(way["name"="laksegade"] (55.6150, 12.4529, 55.7326, 12.6507););out body;>;out skel qt;; --> (55.6150, 12.4529, 55.7326, 12.6507) is the bounding box to contain the search`
2. Decompose the response into individual points along the route segments
3. Use these points to draw a linestring

Hope this helps someone else.